# How to toggle everything EXCEPT the <b> tags

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a summary view for my blog, and I think it can be done with jQuery.
My idea,  is to hide EVERY element on the page excluding only the h1, h2, img and b tags.
Any idea about how I can do that selection?

This is an easy example:

Original state:

```
h1: Blog Title, it remains
p: First sentence of the post
p: Second sentence of the post
img: /foo/bar.png, it remains
b: This is a bold text, it remains
```

When jQuery button clicked:

```
h1: Blog Title, it remains
img: /foo/bar.png, it remains
b: This is a bold text, it remains
```

I've been working around withe the :not selector and .not method, but I dont seem to be able to achieve what Im looking for.

As always, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try .map for each element and if it matches those you don't want then add display:none

Comment: _"I've been working around withe the :not selector and .not method, but I dont seem to be able to achieve what Im looking for."_ Can you include the  `javascript` that you tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've managed to hide most of the content of the page I wanted by using selectors like aside, #comments, etc...
The only thing left is to hide all the <p> content EXCEPT the <b> tags content.

Comment: wrap all the content sections you want to hide in `<div>`'s with common class

Comment: I've created a small Codepen: http://codepen.io/Gekyzo/pen/vyPdqo

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.nextUntil()`, `.hide()`

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("h1").nextUntil("img", "p").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<h1>Blog Title, it remains</h1>
<p>First sentence of the post</p>
<p>Second sentence of the post</p>
<img src="/foo/bar.png" alt="it remains" />
<b>This is a bold text, it remains</b>

<h1>Blog Title, it remains</h1>
<p>First sentence of the post</p>
<p>Second sentence of the post</p>
<img src="/foo/bar.png" alt="it remains" />
<b>This is a bold text, it remains</b>
```

---

> but the only problem I see is when there's a  tag inside a
>
> ,
>   because I want to hide only the p content that is NOT on the B tag

If expected result is `<p>` elements which contain `<b>` element to continue to be displayed after `button` element is clicked you can use selector `"p:not(:has(b))"` as second parameter to `.nextAll()` to exclude `p` element which contain `b` elements from returned jQuery object.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("h1").nextUntil("img", "p:not(:has(b))").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<h1>Blog Title, it remains</h1>
<p>First sentence of the post</p>
<p><b>Second</b> sentence of the post</p>
<img src="/foo/bar.png" alt="it remains" />
<b>This is a bold text, it remains</b>

<h1>Blog Title, it remains</h1>
<p><b>First</b> sentence of the post</p>
<p>Second sentence of the post</p>
<img src="/foo/bar.png" alt="it remains" />
<b>This is a bold text, it remains</b>
```

Comment: This answer is great, but the only problem I see is when there's a <b> tag inside a <p>, because I want to hide only the p content that is NOT on the B tag.

Comment: _"but the only problem I see is when there's a <b> tag inside a <p>, because I want to hide only the p content that is NOT on the B tag"_ Where is this described as a requirement at Question? No `html` appears at Question. Description of `html` at Question does not contain `<p>` element containing `<b>` element. What do you mean by "on the B tag"?

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain myself properly, english is not my first language.
What I mean is, I want to hide all the paragraph of the page, including those who have bold text inside.
What I would like to keep visible are those bold texts within the paragraphs.
For example:

This is a regular paragraph **with a bold text**.

My outcome should be:

**with a bold text**

Comment: Language is not issue, nor valid reason for deferring responsibility of including actual requirement at text of Question. No `<b>` elements appear at text at original Question as child nodes of parent `<p>` element. Original Question does not describe `<p>` elements containing `<b>` elements where `<p>` element should have `display` set to `none`, though child element `<b>` remains visible. You have changed requirement again. Again,  at comment. Have you not read the links previously posted at comments http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Yes I've read the how-to-ask FAQ, as you point my original question was not correct as I didnt include a <b> tag as a child node of a <p> although this was my main concenr. I apologize for that.